Go directly in INSERT mode after clicking mouse in SELECT mode in IdeaVim plugin
I am using IdeaVim plugin for PhpStorm. Is it possible to go back in INSERT mode after highlighting some code with a mouse and eventually clicking in a specific place? Here is what I mean:

After I highlight with mouse and click on some specific place, it goes back to NORMAL mode:

I would like it to go directly into INSERT mode, is there a configuration for it in .ideavimrc? It gets very irritating having to click one extra time to continue typing.

I'm not aware of a setting like that, but I'm also not sure why you would want it. I think normal mode is the "normal" mode because it's the most useful, and most of the time it's what you want. I navigate around much more frequently than I type new text. Typing i to enter insert mode before typing the text itself does not feel like a burden to me.

However. In vim or neovim, if I start out in insert mode, use the mouse to click in different places, double-click or triple-click to select some text, then click again somewhere else, I am still in insert mode. This is not true in IdeaVIM. Since the behavior is different from vim's, you could make the case that it is a bug in IdeaVIM.
So you could try filing a bug report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM and ideally also file a pull request with the fix at https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim
